# total array value, keep decimal points

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to calculate a total from the values in an array.

I've tried several different approaches, but starting to struggle with the wonders of number calculations in JS.

As an example, this is my array:

```
["0.20", "1.20"]
```

and how i've been trying to get a total from these values:

```
var totalPrice = 0;
var arrLength = arr.length;
while(arrLength--)
    totalPrice += parseFloat(Math.round(arr[arrLength] * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

However, this returns `01.200.20`.

If I modify the array to have only one value, `0.20`, this returns `00.20`.

How can I get a total value from the array that will retain the decimal places?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6ddnjsc/2/)

FYI - the fiddle also contains some objects which generate the array, if an item is set to `true`.

Comment: The `.toFixed()` function returns a string, not a number.

Comment: @Pointy is correct.  If you want to retain the decimal places, why not just apply `.toFixed()` on your final result?

Comment: You also don't need the `parseFloat` because the `* 100` will already coerce the string values to numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing string concatenation instead of adding the floats.  Just use the `parseFloat`, then get your decimal places at the end when you need the actual string representation.

```js
  var arr = ["0.20", "1.20"];

  var totalPrice = 0;
  var arrLength = arr.length;
  while (arrLength--) {
    totalPrice += parseFloat(arr[arrLength]);
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = totalPrice.toFixed(2);
```

```html
<div id="result">x</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @MatthewG, that certainly clears things up! A lot cleaner than the original I had too.